# How to propagate local branch deletion to remote in 1 step - git, github

Tags: linux, git, github

When I want to delete a branch locally on git and propagate this to the GitHub repo, I use this 2-step method:

```
~$ git branch -d [branch_name]
~$ git push origin :[branch_name]
```

Is there any command to delete a branch locally an automatically propagate this modification to the remote repo on GitHub?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git config alias.yourcommandnamehere \
        '! f() { git branch -d $1; git push origin :$1; }; f'

git yourcommandnamehere branch_name
```

just a note, git won't honor aliases for builtins.  [Many of them do have config items](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) to supply defaults.